# How to insert blank rows to create a uniform output in an Oracle SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Currently, my query pulls incomplete raw data in the following example layout. There could be between 1 and 3 A's, B's, etc so I need some way to check the number of rows that currently exist and how many need to be added to A/B/etc to get them to all out 3 rows.

| Column 4 | Column 8 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 3 |
| E | 1 |
| E | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| F | 2 |

I would like to add in a number of blank columns to create a uniform layout:

| Column 4 | Column 8 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 * |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 * |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 * |
| C | 2 * |
| C | 3 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 3 * |
| E | 1 * |
| E | 2 * |
| E | 3 * |
| F | 1 |
| F | 2 * |
| F | 3 |

My current query:

```
select 
DATABASE1.TABLE1.COLUMN4,
DATABASE2.TABLE3.COLUMN8

from DATABASE1.TABLE1

inner join DATABASE2.TABLE2 on DATABASE1.TABLE1.MATCHINGCOLUMN1 = DATABASE2.TABLE2. MATCHINGCOLUMN1
inner join DATABASE2.TABLE3 on DATABASE2.TABLE2. MATCHINGCOLUMN2 = DATABASE2.TABLE3. MATCHINGCOLUMN2

where Column10 = 'PreferredOrderType'
and Column1 in (00000000)
```

I've tried replacing INNER JOIN with variations of OUTER JOIN with no success. I've seen some suggestions to use UNION or COALESCE but I have not been able to successfully implement them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Create a table that just has the values 1, 2, 3 and join with it.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  `Col4` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO t
  (`Col4`)
VALUES
  ('A'),
  ('B'),
  ('C'),
  ('C'),
  ('D'),
  ('E'),
  ('E'),
  ('E'),
  ('F');

CREATE TABLE nums (
  `n` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO nums
  (`n`)
VALUES
  ('1'),
  ('2'),
  ('3');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT Col4, n
FROM t
JOIN nums;
```

| Col4 | n |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| A | 3 |
| B | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| C | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 1 |
| D | 2 |
| D | 3 |
| E | 1 |
| E | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| E | 1 |
| E | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| E | 1 |
| E | 2 |
| E | 3 |
| F | 1 |
| F | 2 |
| F | 3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7kJPCY25yCFwZHCGjYRh1C/0)

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am unfortunately unable to create tables due to insufficient privileges. Is there a way to produce this affect without the Schema portion?

Comment: There's almost certainly a way to create a temporary values table as a CTE, but I don't know oracle enough to direct you to the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Hello other approach in Oracle

select distinct col1, level
from yourtable
connect by level <=3
order by 1;